# Is there a way to reduce the number of hits on the db

Tags: sql-server, database-administration, c#, linq

I'm new to C#, ASP.NET MVC and SQL Server, but I have got this code working

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Parse(start);
DateTime endDate = DateTime.Parse(end);

ViewData["TotalDuringPeriod"] = db.AlcoholForms.Count(x => x.CreatedDate >= startDate && x.CreatedDate <= endDate);
ViewData["TotalUniqueClientsDuringPeriod"] = db.AlcoholForms.Where(x => x.CreatedDate >= startDate && x.CreatedDate <= endDate).Select(x => x.ClientId).Distinct().Count();
ViewData["TotalGateNew"] = db.AlcoholForms.Count(x => x.ReferredTo == "Gate" && x.Reengagement == false && (x.CreatedDate >= startDate && x.CreatedDate <= endDate));
ViewData["TotalGateReengagment"] = db.AlcoholForms.Count(x => x.ReferredTo == "Gate" && x.Reengagement && (x.CreatedDate >= startDate && x.CreatedDate <= endDate));
ViewData["TotalSwitchNew"] = db.AlcoholForms.Count(x => x.ReferredTo == "Switch" && x.Reengagement == false && (x.CreatedDate >= startDate && x.CreatedDate <= endDate));
ViewData["TotalSwitchReengagement"] = db.AlcoholForms.Count(x => x.ReferredTo == "Switch" && x.Reengagement && (x.CreatedDate >= startDate && x.CreatedDate <= endDate));

List<ReportAlcoholReferals> reportData = db.AlcoholForms.Where(x => x.Referral && (x.CreatedDate >= startDate && x.CreatedDate <= endDate)).Select(x => new ReportAlcoholReferals()
            {
                FirstName = x.Client.FirstName,
                LastName = x.Client.LastName,
                Date = x.CreatedDate,                 
                ClientId = x.ClientId,
                AlcoholForm = x
            }).OrderBy(x => x.AlcoholForm.ReferredTo).ToList();
            return View(reportData);
```

Now it works but I am hitting the database 7 times? Is there a better way of doing this?
How much of a performance issue is it

Comment: Sounds like you need a List<AlcoholForms> so you can query once, and then leverage that object in all of your subsequent LINQ queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would handle this, simply in the context of hitting the database less often. There are probably other improvements you could make as well, but that's not what you're asking for.

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Parse(start);
DateTime endDate = DateTime.Parse(end);
List<AlcoholForms> formsList = db.AlcoholForms.Where(x => x.CreatedDate >= startDate && x.CreatedDate <= endDate).ToList();

ViewData["TotalDuringPeriod"] = formsList.Count();
ViewData["TotalUniqueClientsDuringPeriod"] = formsList.Select(x => x.ClientId).Distinct().Count();
ViewData["TotalGateNew"] = formsList.Count(x => x.ReferredTo == "Gate" && x.Reengagement == false);
ViewData["TotalGateReengagment"] = formsList.Count(x => x.ReferredTo == "Gate" && x.Reengagement);
ViewData["TotalSwitchNew"] = formsList.Count(x => x.ReferredTo == "Switch" && x.Reengagement == false);
ViewData["TotalSwitchReengagement"] = formsList.Count(x => x.ReferredTo == "Switch" && x.Reengagement);
List<ReportAlcoholReferals> reportData = formsList.Where(x => x.Referral).Select(x => new ReportAlcoholReferals()
{
    FirstName = x.Client.FirstName,
    LastName = x.Client.LastName,
    Date = x.CreatedDate,                 
    ClientId = x.ClientId,
    AlcoholForm = x
}).OrderBy(x => x.AlcoholForm.ReferredTo).ToList();

return View(reportData);
```

The list declaration for formsList means that the database will be queried once and store the results in the List object. From there, you can continue to use LINQ to break out your data.

Comment: Out of curiosity - does this actually improve performances? A list with seven items in it, versus seven strings, would still be equal in size no?

Comment: This is something that you'd need to test.  It's *possible* for this to be a win, due primarily to the reduced round trips to the database.  However, you're now pulling *everything* back from the database instead of a very small amount of data that is pretty heavily filtered.  Whether or not this ends up being a "win" is going to depend on many factor such as just how far away the DB is from the application, how much data is actually filtered, how much data *isn't* filtered, etc.  For example, if only 1% of the records are between the date range, this is likely a net loss in performance.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage the performance problem has nothing to do with strings or their size.

Comment: Can you please explain to me what the performance hits/improvements would be with a `List` and `string`?

Answer (score 0):

Your third through sixth queries can be turned from four different counts into one grouping that captures the count of each group:

```
var lookup = db.AlcoholForms.Where(x => x.CreatedDate >= startDate && 
        x.CreatedDate <= endDate)
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.ReferredTo, x.Reengagement },
        (key, items) => new{key, count = items.Count()})
    .ToDictionary(group => group.key, group => group.count);

ViewData["TotalGateNew"] = lookup[
    new { ReferredTo = "Gate", Reengagement = false }];
ViewData["TotalGateReengagment"] = lookup[
    new { ReferredTo = "Gate", Reengagement = true }];
ViewData["TotalSwitchNew"] = lookup[
    new { ReferredTo = "Switch", Reengagement = false }];
ViewData["TotalSwitchReengagement"] = lookup[
    new { ReferredTo = "Switch", Reengagement = true }];
```

Answer (score 0):

The number of roundtrips is not necessarily a bad thing.  Have you profiled the seven hits to see if they are really taking any time?  My guess would be that they aren't, which means you're okay (unless this will be running on a very high volume site).

One alternative would be to write a T-SQL stored procedure that returns the all the values you need in one shot.  You could then capture the result as an object, or just a list of ints, or whatever.

Comment: A stored procedure would still query the database multiple times.

Comment: @Ellesedil but it could be written to do it much more efficiently (think Servy's answer but in T-SQL), plus fewer round trips if I understand the problem correctly.

Comment: @Ellesedil The point is that your reducing the network traffic between the application and the database.  The problem with the OP's code is not the time the DB spends actually generating a response for each result, but rather getting the request from the application to the DB and the response from the DB to the application.  *That* traffic gets cut by a factor of ~7 by doing this.